# I need to perform a kernel upgrade on a live system. Best practices?

Tags: boot, kernel, upgrade

**Steps taken so far:**

```
apt-cache search linux-image*
apt-get install linux-image-...
```

I was now thinking of rebooting and selecting the new kernel when it appears on the GRUB menu, however:

1. Is it best practice to force GRUB to boot the new kernel by editing configuration files? Or would it be fine to manually select the kernel as this server is not rebooted frequently?
2. Is it possible to delete the kernel that appears under `uname -r` while I am using that kernel? Or will the shutdown and reboot process fail?

Comment: Can someone explain why this has been downvoted? I have never done this before, so am looking to see if there's anything I am missing/a better way to do this.

Comment: Mouse over the down arrow; the popup says "*This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*".  Downvotes without comment may be presumed to be for at least one of those reasons.

Comment: @MadHatter fair enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When upgrading kernel, always have at least one known-good kernel (meaning a kernel that you have  already succesfuly booted).

As long as you have access to the console, so you can manually switch to this known-good, its fine to change the default kernel to your newly installed.

If you do not have access to the console, you probably should use grub's fallback mechanism and set kernels `panic` parameter.

Comment: Wasn't aware of the panic parameter - that's a great failback mechanism!